# In Function Import, The selected stored procedure returns no columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure to insert values into a table where the primary key will be auto incremented. when I try to import this in Visual Studio 2013, In function Imports when I select "Get Column Information" it says "The selected procedure or function" returns no columns.

I read about it many articles and also included SET FMTONLY OFF in my code but it still does not work. Amateur in ASP.Net and C#. So can anyone explain to me What to do in a clear manner

```
      USE [DB_Name]
      GO
      /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_makePost]    Script Date:   04-04-2015 19:16:04 ******/
     SET FMTONLY OFF
     GO
     SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO
     CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_makePost]
        @FK_strUser_Id varchar(11),
        @strPost_Title varchar(100),
        @strPost_Content varchar(1000),
        @dTime_of_post datetime,
        @iUp_Vote int,
        @iDown_Vote int,
        @FK_strRootword_Id varchar(11)
     as 
     begin

     DECLARE @PK_strPost_Id VARCHAR(11);
     DECLARE @PreFix VARCHAR(10) = 'POST';
     DECLARE @Id INT;

     SELECT @Id = ISNULL(COUNT(PK_strPost_Id),0) + 1 FROM Tbl_Post
     SELECT @PK_strPost_Id = @PreFix + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)
     insert into Tbl_Name values(@PK_strPost_Id,@FK_strUser_Id,@strPost_Title,@strPost_Content,@dTime_of_post,@iUp_Vote,@iDown_Vote,@FK_strRootword_Id)
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure doesn't do any data retrieve operation (ie, any `SELECT`). It just does an `INSERT` plus some variable manipulation. Those `SELECT`s out there only assign variables too, so nothing really produces any kind of result set.

Therefore client programs are completely right in that there are no columns or any kind of output from this procedure. Maybe you intended to add some sort of return table?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the stored procedure as a data source for your front end application. Now for it to have data, it has to end with a `SELECT` clause, because only then can it have data. Clearly your application is *expecting* data. So without going into much details,

1. either you need to tell your application to stop expecting data.
2. or, modify the procedure so that it starts giving data.

Probably you would need to add a `SELECT * FROM Tbl_Name` in the end of stored proc or something similar.

Comment: It doesn't has to *end* with a `SELECT`, it can be anywhere really, as long as it's executed. Moreover, there can be more than one, and don't forget about the return value and output parameters, if the application is prepared to use them when fit.